# Infiniti G37 Changes Settings on Power Off

Tags: electrical, infiniti, g37

2009 Infiniti G37 sedan.

I'm losing audio and display settings every time I power off the car for more than a minute or two.

I checked all the fuses (in the cabin and in the two under-hood fuse panels) and the battery seems fine. Any thoughts on what to check next? It's not a default state since it's the third page of radio presets, the brightness is low, and the bass is at 0 - so it seems like it's the 'last' settings that were on the key or something... but I can't see anywhere that links the settings and the key.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!